# Using VBA, how to highlight a value that is in a list in one column on one sheet if the value exists in range on a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of ids in one column on Sheet "A". On sheet "B" i have these ids spread out in a table (a range). How do i search through the range to see if each value listed on sheet A exists on Sheet B? I'm wanting to make sure that all values in the one column on Sheet A exist on Sheet B. This macro is supposed to check and Highlight the values that do exist. Thus, any values that dont exist will not be highlighted and i can easily address. Currently we are manually updating but i need it to be dynamic with as many changes as we are making.

Below is what i have tried so far but am getting a "Next without For" error. i've coded in vba but its been a LONG time. Any help is appreciated.
Btw, i didnt really care about the color until i get it working so i just picked a number.

```
Sub CaseIdCheck()

    Dim i, j, x As Integer
    Dim intValueToFind, testCaseId, tciPass1, tciPass2 As String
    Dim range1, range2 As Range

    range1 = Application.GotoActiveWorkbook.Sheets("B").Range("C4:U50")
    range2 = Application.GotoActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A").Range("i3:i145")

    For x = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A").CountA(Columns(9))
    If Cells(x, 9).Value <> Null Then
       testCaseId = Sheets("A").Cells(x, 9).Value

        For i = 1 To 100
            For j = 1 To 100
                If Sheets("B").Cells(i, j).Value = testCaseId Then
                    Sheets("A").Cells(x, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                Else
            Next j
        Next i

                End If
    Next x
    Else
    MsgBox ("end")
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the error might be occurring because you have `If` blocks interspersed with `For` blocks. Have you tried re-ordering the code?

Comment: No i havent but it gave me the error on the "Next J" portion. I have it written the way logically i think it should work.
Pull value from sheet A if not null, check range on sheet B for value, if it exists then highlight cell on sheet A. rinse and repeat
the reason for checking if null is so i dont end up with a million colored blank cells in sheet A. There are blank cells in the range on B so thats what that is for.

Comment: Remove the `Else` above `Next j`, replace it with `End If`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this need to be VBA? You can do this with a named range and conditional highlighting.

Create a new named range (we'll call it `rngCheck`) that is defined with this named range formula:

```
=B!$1:$1048576
```

Then apply this conditional format to sheet "A" column I:

```
=COUNTIF(rngCheck,I1)>0
```

And select the desired color (the RGB of ColorIndex 36 is R 255, G 255, B153)

Comment: I assume your =B$... statement is for the entire worksheet? My data in sheet B that i need to check is on multi columns and rows. I'll give it a shot while i wait for your response.

Comment: Yeah, `=B!$1:$1048576` is the entire sheet.  If it's just for specific columns and rows, you can specify that with `=B!$C$4:$U$50`

Comment: Just tried it out and it is EXACTLY (can i increase the font size anymore?) what i was looking for. Thank you so much!